# Cloud-based Continuous Build Server for Google App Engine Projects

Tags: google-app-engine

I've been asked to setup a continuous build server for a Google App Engine project (python). Has anyone already configured a build-server in the cloud that includes the Google App Engine SDK?

My ideal solution would be a public Amazon EC2 AMI (or Google Compute Engine image) that I could just clone, launch and configure. Our GAE code is hosted in Github, so my goal is to setup Github to ping the build server every time there is a new commit to the Github repo and have the cloud-based build server instance rebuild and test the GAE project.

Anyone know of an existing solution?

Answer (score 0):

CloudBees is integrated for free with Jenkins.